# JDBC input logstash plugin fetch data from mysql multiple times

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Logstash jdbc input plugin fetch data from mysql multiple time and keep creating documents in elasticsearch

For 600 rows in mysql, it creates 8581812 documents in elasticsearch

I have created multiple config files to fetch data from each table in mysql and put in /etc/logstash/conf.d folder
Start logstash service as sudo systemctl start logstash
Run following command to execute files
/usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/spt_audit_event.conf
Data successfully fetched

```
input{
jdbc {
jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/share/jdbc_driver/mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar"
jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://:3306/"
jdbc_user => ""
jdbc_password => ""
statement => "select * from spt_identity"
}
}

output {
elasticsearch {
"hosts" => "localhost:9200"
"index" => ""
}
stdout {}
}
```

Actual Results

Number of documents in elasticsearch keep on increasing and reached to 8581812 but there are only 600 rows in mysql table
Is it bug in plugin or I'm doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention the unqiue id for elasticsearch

In order to avoid the duplication issues at `elasticsearch` you may need to add the unique id for the documents at `elasticsearch`.

Modify the `logstash.conf` by adding the `"document_id" => "%{studentid}"` in the output like below.

```
output {
  stdout { codec => json_lines }
  elasticsearch {
  "hosts" => "localhost:9200"
  "index" => "test-migrate"
  "document_id" => "%{studentid}"
  }
```

In your case it wont be studentid, but something else. Find the same and add it to your configuration.

Comment: Thanks for update                                                                                                                                                                  If i run logstash as service. Would it automatically take conf file from conf.d folder and how frequently it happens.